# Force.com attaches to web address

Tags: security, web, service, salesforce, force.com

When I type a web address in my web browser, "force.com" or "salesforce.com" comes up in it. Here's an example: https://k12parentportal.force.com/portal_enrollmenthome>. Everything is correct except force.com being in it. I think the actual address is: https://K12parentportal/enrollmenthome>; but, it's happened so often that I can't type the real address. It happens in Internet Explorer and Firefox. I reset IE, but it keeps happening. This has been going on for several weeks. It will also redirect my browser to "salesforce.com". I had never been to your website until my browser was redirected. I ran malewarebtyes and HitmanPro Anti Malware to remove it, but it's still there. I have tried everything to remove it from my computer, but nothing works. Can you please help me with this? Thank you. Beverly `

Answer (score 0):

1. This is a website for programmers, not a place to talk to Salesforce the company.
2. This is not a valid url because it is not a valid domain name:  `https://K12parentportal/enrollmenthome`   HINT, no .com
3. force.com is a business platform and is trustworthy.  Google it.